# Is passing a redux store & dispatch via thunk a reasonable alternative to directly importing the redux store into a file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

According to this, [Redux FAQ: Can or should I create multiple stores? Can I import my store directly, and use it in components myself?](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself), one should not import their store directly for use.

In React Components, we could use the `connect` wrapper.

I have a Client I want to manage all communication with and logic regarding a 3rd party service. Ideally, this client would be able to dispatch and read state from the store.

To avoid directly importing the store, I plan to leverage thunk and do the following:

**Action Creator:**

```
export function initializeClient() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {

    const { token } = await Api.createToken();

    return Client.initialize(token, dispatch, getState);
  }
}
```

Within the client, I would essentially do this:

**Client**

```
class Client {
  dispatch;
  getState;

  async initializeClient(token, dispatch, getState) {
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
    this.getState = getState;

    // Process token
  }

  // Other functions...
}
```

What I did might be an anti-pattern, but I feel like it would allow for one to still do server-side rendering and gets past importing the store directly.

My biggest concern is keeping a reference to dispatch and getState for so long, but I can't imagine the functions ever change... so I think that should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

It'll run, I guess, but I would recommend [putting that client into a custom middleware instead](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live):

> Middleware are the right place for persistent connections like websockets in a Redux app, for several reasons:
>
> - Middleware exist for the lifetime of the application
> - Like with the store itself, you probably only need a single instance of a given connection that the whole app can use
> - Middleware can see all dispatched actions and dispatch actions themselves. This means a middleware can take dispatched actions and turn those into messages sent over the websocket, and dispatch new actions when a message is received over the websocket.
> - A websocket connection instance isn't serializable, so it doesn't belong in the store state itself